# proc sql how to permanently save a variable into the dataset?

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I created a dynamic variable "DepressedState" in proc sql and I want to save it as a permanent variable into the dataset "phsc524.nacc1". I was wondering how can I do that? Or can I permanently save the tables I joined in SQL?

```
    proc SQL;

    create table MaxDepPerPerson as
    (
    select 
    NACCID, max(DEPRESSION) as Depressed
    FROM phsc524.nacc1 
    group by NACCID
    );

    select count(NACCID) as number_ofpatients, DepressedState
    from 
    (
    select 
    NACCID, 
    case Depressed
    when 1 then '1'
    when 0 then '0'
    else '4'
    end as DepressedState
    from 
    (
    select a.NACCID, a.NACCVNUM, a.NACCUDSD, a.NACCALZD, 
    b.Depressed 
    from phsc524.nacc1 as a
    right join MaxDepPerPerson as b
    on  (a.NACCVNUM = 1 and a.NACCUDSD = "Dementia" and 
    a.NACCALZD =1 and b.NACCID = a.NACCID
    )))

    group by DepressedState
    ;
    quit;
```

I have read about "proc sql select into", not sure if it would work here? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `create table phsc524.newtablename as select ...`

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.  Your code already demonstrates how to create a dataset.  Why not just use a CREATE TABLE for the step that is deriving the values of the new variable?  If you want the dataset with the new variables to also have the old variable then include them in the list of variables selected.